# error when including <chrono>

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I've tried to include the  class to measure the time it takes for a segment of code to run. These are my includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
```

my error message is:

```
FILENAME.cpp:4: chrono: No such file or directory
```

What's the matter with my code?

Comment: Are you using a C++11 compiler? With g++, try giving it "-std=c++11". With clang it's probably the same.

Comment: OT: that should be `<cmath>`

Comment: Please find out your g++ version using the command `g++ -version`.

Comment: I'm going to put the comment in an answer so this question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

From my comment:
Are you using a C++11 compiler? With g++, try giving it "-std=c++11".

```
g++ -std=c++11 myfile.cpp
```

With clang it's probably the same.

Comment: On a side note, if you're using an older compiler, the flag `-std=c++0x` may be required.